# Is Terraform capable of managing roles/owner bindings and memberships?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

After several unsuccessful attempts to include a working iam policy definition (including `roles/owner` binding) in the terraform config I came across the following information in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/setIamPolicy) for `projects.setIamPolicy` method:

> To be added as an owner, a user must be invited via Cloud Platform
>   console and must accept the invitation.

Does that apply to Terraforma and its `google_project_iam_policy` resource as well? If so, that in my opinion makes this resource unusable because:

- if your config contains `roles/owner` binding, then you get a failure
- if your config doesn't contain `roles/owner` binding, then the owner is removed from your project for good upon the `terraform apply` (i.e. a lock-out scenario)

My latest tests were done using the `google_project_iam_member` resource:

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "project_owner" {
  count         = "${length(var.owners)}"
  project       = "${var.project_id}"
  role          = "roles/owner"
  member        = "${element(var.owners, count.index)}"
}
```

results in:

```
* google_project_iam_binding.project_owner: Error applying IAM policy for project "<project_name>": Error setting IAM policy for project "<project_name>": googleapi: Error 400: Request contains an invalid argument., badRequest
```

Comment: Did you try that setIamPolicy API with serviceAccount ? I am asking that because [the document](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/setIamPolicy) says "The owner role can be granted only to user and serviceAccount.".

Comment: Did you attach the `Admin Service Account User` role to the service account ?